# JHipster Generated Application Failed Sign-In Shows Wrong Message

Tags: jhipster

I am using the latest version of the jHipster-generator (Version 5.0.2).  The generated application contains a customized failure Handler which overrides the jHipster generated ajaxAuthenticationFailureHandler to determine which of two Failed Sign-in Messages should appear.  The generated application only displays "Unauthorized", which is neither of the error messages designed to be shown.

Debugging the code indicates neither the ajaxAuthenticationSuccessHandler, nor my customized failure Handler are being called.  Where can I look to determine the current routing being generated by the latest jHipster generated application?

Comment: Which authentication type? Maybe a conflict with Zalando problem library?

Comment: I'm using HTTP Session Authentication

Comment: Have a look at Zalando's AuthenticationAdviceTrait under debugger, maybe it takes priority over your handler.

Comment: I set a debugging breakpoint in the AuthenticationAdviceTrait class, but it didn't fire, so it is something else.

Comment: Have you tried to set an exception breakpoint on org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException ?

Comment: Yes, I have set a breakpoint on org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException, but the breakpoint never fires, since the code isn't executed.